# Why didn't anyone go back in time to prevent the damage cause by Narada's actions?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-2009, star-trek-reboot

Why was the timeline not repaired after the Narada came back in time and changed everything? I have seem the Time Travel Repairmen go back in time for much less impactful things than this. So why not? Just how picky are the Time Cops?

Comment: The Narada going back in time created a new Universe - the old Universe carried on as normal.  So the Narada became a part of events - fixing it would have destroyed a universe.